# Error on database connection while uploading laravel project to shared hosting (bluehost)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to connect my laravel 5.3 project to bluehost shared hosting database. Recently I am getting the following error

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 119:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Could not find a good solution to solve the problem. Please help me!

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information on your code / your context

Comment: 1. .env file? 2. db driver? 3. have you played with `php artisan config:...`?